# what's the use of keeping ";" after if conditional in C?

Tags: c

Yesterday I was asked a question in an exam, the code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i=5;
  if(i==5);
  printf("I am printing\n");
  return 0;
}
```

with and without ";" after if conditional I am getting the same result can anyone help me what's the use of keeping the ";" after an if conditional?

Comment: Set `int i=42;` (leave `i==5` as is) and see what happens with and then without the `;` after the `if()`..

Comment: still output is getting printed, that means if condition is being ignored. so, does that mean when we keep ; after if conditional it will be ignored?

Comment: check with and without the semi-colon, after setting `i=42`

Comment: That's complete fantasy. If you followed chux instructions verbatim *and* rebuilt your program before run, *nothing* gets printed. [with-semi-colon](https://ideone.com/tG4Jr2) vs. [without-semi-colon](https://ideone.com/FH7UxQ)

Comment: after changing i=42 and if i remove the semicolon if conditional is working normally so nothing gets printed but when I keep the semi colon print statement is getting executed.

Comment: yeah, so if you put a semicolon after an if condition, it's useless

Comment: Exactly. To answer your question, there is no use in terminating an empty if-clause (synonymous with `if(exp){}` ). If you were counting on the side effects of evaluating `exp` you could just as well simply do `exp;` .IF the instructor is looking for some non-runtime answer (i.e. a quick way to disable-without-destroying the logic of an if-test, dropping a semi-colon in is one way to do that. But I *seriously* doubt that was on the radar when this question was asked.

Answer (score -1):

Here semicolon after if condition says there is NULL Statement to execute. It has no impact on next statements. It is rarely used. You can understand more with some changes in code. Try printf statement within if condition and change the value of i. Then see output changes;

```
    int i=10; 
    if(i==5)
  printf("I am printing\n");
```

Comment: **Note:** The `NULL` has a different meaning in C. It is the type of `(void *)0` that is used for pointers.

Comment: @RohanBari Detail: The _type_ of `NULL` is `void*` or `int` or `long` or any of an _integer constant expression_.

Comment: In other words, `null statement` != NULL.  It means, all side effects before the ';' character, must be carried out before any of the effects after.

Answer (score -1):

When you put the semicolon after the `if()` it gets ignored and it prints the next statement like below

```
int i=5;
    if(i==5);{
        printf("I am Printing");
    }
```

but if you try to run it with `else` statement it will show you an error that there is no `if` statement like below

```
int i=5;
    if(i==5);{
        printf("I am Printing");
    }else{
        printf("I am Not Printing)
    }
```

So the main concept is when you put a semicolon at the end of any line it terminates that sentence and in your case when you're putting a semicolon after `if` it terminates the working of `if` statement

Comment: No it's NOT ignored. The compiler really is interested in every single semicolon that the optimizer can't reasonably eliminate.  But yes, it does create an empty if block. I don't think your second example will compile, due to the non-empty scope following the empty if statement. Did you test before posting?

Comment: Yes I tested before posting and I know it will show an error that's the thing I want to show that the compiler will terminate the `if()` statements working

Comment: You should post the expected compiler errors. Your post doesn't mention them at all.